# Not getting input from get_query_var

Tags: query, tags, variables

I want to pass on values from a search field and use those values to show posts with specific tags. I'm using get_query_var for this. I'm almost there, but not getting the values in my query. When I echo my both input values I get the right results on the result page but not in my query

I'm using these:

```
<?php echo $_GET['area'] ?>  <?php echo $_GET['persons'] ?>
```

Which outputs South 8 (that is correct). But how do I get this in my query to work, anyone?

Input is given by a form select name="area". I'm trying to fetch the values from my URL on the searchresults page which looks like this
http://xxx/search/?area=South&persons=8

```
$TagArea = get_query_var('area');
$TagPersons = get_query_var('persons');
```

The new vars I would like to use in my foreach query

```
$rand_posts = get_posts("tag={$TagArea+$TagPersons}");
```

And not getting this to work. If I replace {$TagArea+$TagPersons} into South+8 (hardcoded) I get perfect results. Anyone that can help me get the vars into the query the right way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a simple PHP problem: Single `'` quotes do not expand the variables, but treat it as simple string. Use `"` double quotes instead: `"tag={$TagArea}"`. Also care about properly validating input, sanitizing output and escaping data before you hand it over to the database.

Comment: sorry if it is offtopic, but since I'm trying to get values into the tag section of the wordpress query I thought it should be ok to post it here. Thank you for the direction, but I'm not getting it fixed by changing single into double quotes. I tried to echo the values instead but that is making the mess a lot bigger. Also tried to use the { } but also no luck. I'm not sure if the get_query_var is the right way and maybe just use $_GET['Area'] instead.

Comment: Your problem is that you get nothing from the query var function? Edit your question and ahow a full example please.

Comment: edited, hopefully better this way.

Comment: Got it after a few other tries.

`$area = $_GET[‘area’];
$persons = $_GET['persons’];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => "$area+$persons” ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the query and with the direction kaiser gave I got it working.

```
$area = $_GET['area'];
$persons = $_GET['persons'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => "$area+$persons" ) );
```

Comment: Quick not: Sanitize the data before you send it to the DB. Else even a request from a browser can be used to hack your database.

Comment: Thanks kaiser for the notice. I'm not using user input but predefined drop down menus. Also checking if an option is selected and using $_POST instead of $_GET. Is this enough or do I need to include htmlspecialchars or something? Any tips/advice?

Comment: Never trust any input - it could have been modified. Use `filter_var()` and `filter_input()` and friends (see: php.net). Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok just to be sure :) Using POST instead of GET, before using the var in my query I'm using valid_options to check if any incoming input is in the list, after that I'm using `filter_var($area, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` and put it into another new var and that one I'm using in my query. Also checking if it's not empty (-1 in this case), because then I'm not using the var at all.

Anything else that I might consider? htmlspecialchars? or is that not necessary with the valid_options check?